# Sendkeys from within hybrid Batch-VBScript file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, bluetooth, settings, sendkeys

I can't figure out, what wrong I am doing here.

Checkout below script, in which I intend to toggle Bluetooth enability setting thro' `SendKeys` method:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

start "" /b explorer.exe ms-settings:bluetooth

%SendKeys% "{TAB}" & %SendKeys% " "

goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.AppActivate "settings":WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

It doesn't do keytrokes, just opens the Bluetooth settings window and stays as it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "ms-settings:bluetooth"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

NOTE: I am complying with that list of rules. My program is simple rather than needlessly complex, indirect, and doing things the wrong way.